# VS Code - Shortcut to programming language documentation

Tags: php, intellisense, visual-studio-code

At the moment I use VScode for my PHP work. Is there a shortcut to get to the documentation of php.net? At the moment I have to click several times to reach the online article.

[image: work flow at the moment to get help]